# How to bind Radio Button group created dynamically using Data Template to a List?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, radio-button, datatemplate

I have a list called "CarEngineItems" of "SelectableItems" objects with 2 properties: ItemDescription and isSelected.

```
    namespace DTOs
    {
        class CarEngines : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public static List<SelectableItem> CarEngineItems { get; set; } = new List<SelectableItem>();
    
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }

 namespace Models
    {
        public class SelectableItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
            public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
            protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

I have used the below user control to create a radio button for each item in the list.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <SelectableItem:SelectableItem x:Key="vm"></SelectableItem:SelectableItem>
        <src:RadioButtonCheckedConverter x:Key="RadioButtonCheckedConverter" />
        <CollectionViewSource
                Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=ItemDescription}"
                x:Key="ListingDataView" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupingHeaderTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl Name="RadioGroup" AutomationProperties.Name="RadioGroup" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RadioButton                              
                                 Content="{Binding Path=ItemDescription}"
                                 FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{DynamicResource CustomRadioButton}" Margin="20,0"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I added this user control to my main window.

```
 <uc:CommonRadioButtonGroup x:Name="EnginesGroup"></uc:CommonRadioButtonGroup>
```

In the code behind, I updated the source to this user control as:

```
 InitializeComponent();
 EnginesGroup.RadioGroup.ItemsSource = DTOs.CarEngines.CarEngineItems;
```

The CarEngineItems were added at startup.

```
CarEngines.CarEngineItems.Add(new SelectableItem
            {
                ItemDescription = "V8",
                IsSelected = Properties.Settings.Default.Engines.Equals("V8")
            });
            CarEngines.CarEngineItems.Add(new SelectableItem
            {
                ItemDescription = "Electric",
                IsSelected = Properties.Settings.Default.Engines.Equals("Electric")
            });
```

The current output results in this:
On startup, the the default value V8 is selected as expected.

[Proper binding happens on startup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32sdg.png)

But on clicking the next item in group, it is also selected.

[Why are both selected?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLniY.png)

The ultimate aim is to select a check box (created dynamically) and update only the selected item to a property table on pressing a button (SAVE button). But in this case, the selection is happening for all items.

Comment: Where do you give the RadioButton its group name?

Comment: I just added Group name and multiple selection issue is resolved. But I am using the same user control thrice on the same window. How can I set the group name differently for each user control instance? The problem is, when I select one of the buttons in user control, others become unchecked.

Comment: The GroupName property on the RadioButton instances can be binded to a property on SelectableItem class, which you set from code behind or viewmodel.

Comment: Added another property Item Type and it was used to bind the Group Name. It worked. Thank you for the assist, captain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @o_w 's comment, I am updating the answer.

I added a group name to the Radio Button Group by binding it to another property of SelectableItem.

```
 <ItemsControl Name="RadioGroup" AutomationProperties.Name="RadioGroup" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RadioButton
                                 GroupName="{Binding Path=ItemType}"
                                 Content="{Binding Path=ItemDescription}"
                                 FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                 Style="{DynamicResource CustomRadioButton}" Margin="20,0"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Here's the updated SelectableItem.

```
namespace Models
{
    public class SelectableItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }//New

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
}
```